# Weird Behavior on While Loop PHP

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop, phpexcel

I've been working on a loop with an Array to set the values of an excel cells. For now is working, but sometimes the values have a weird behavior, repeating the data in the cell. The Array came from another file (via POST):

```
$posicionesX = $_POST['postposX'];
$posicionesY = $_POST['postposY'];
$asignadorB=6;
while ($asignadorB <= $lastRowEmpla){
    foreach ($posicionesX as $key=>$value){
       $excelObj->getSheet(2) ->SetCellValue ("E".$asignadorB, $value);
       unset($value);
    $asignadorB++;
    };
};
$asignadorC=6;
while ($asignadorC <= $lastRowEmpla){
    foreach ($posicionesY as $key2=>$value2){
     $excelObj->getSheet(2) ->SetCellValue ("F".$asignadorC, $value2);
     unset($value2);
     //$excelObj->getSheet(2) ->SetCellValue ("F".$asignadorB, );
     $asignadorC++;
   };

 };
 ?>
 <?php  $objWriter->save("../configuracion.xlsx");?>
```

I'm using PHPEXCEL to populate the cells. The Array are Position.Top and Position.Left of some buttons and I need to write this coordinates in the Excel file.

Someone could know what is happening?

Comment: 1.  `unset($value);` and `unset($value2);` are useless and not working at all untill you use `call by reference` mechanism(`&`) or use keys to remove those values. Also why you are doing that is not clear. 2 can you please tell which code actually repeating the values?

Comment: Hi, yeap I figure out that unset doesn't do anything :/ The first While gives me the row  and the foreach inside write the array value (TOP position) in the column 'E' with the row "$asignador". The second While do the same but in another column with the LEFT position

Comment: so where the problem occur?in which code?

Comment: Sadly, both! hahaha. I don't understand what happen. I think maybe, the "save" happen in the middle of the while or something like that. because sometimes PHP send me the error of "unable to save" but then dissapear. I was trying to figure out how to set the save event after the while ends...but I don't know how to do it. Look for a way to asure that the loop ends and be able to save cleanly...any clue? And sometimes, if I check the Excel file, some of the rows after the loop are filled with data..and it shouldn't happen...because the While determinate the limit of the last Row

Comment: can you try like this:- `while ($asignadorB <= $lastRowEmpla){
    foreach ($posicionesX as &$value){
  $excelObj->getSheet(2) ->SetCellValue ("E".$asignadorB, $value);
  unset($value);
  $asignadorB++;
    };
};` and  `while ($asignadorC <= $lastRowEmpla){
    foreach ($posicionesY as &$value2){
  $excelObj->getSheet(2) ->SetCellValue ("F".$asignadorC, $value2);
  unset($value2);
  $asignadorC++;
 };
};` . try and check

Comment: Let me see...and I let u know. :)

Comment: check my edited comment

Comment: Noup :( still happening... I was thinking this loops are called from another page, when I press a button "save coordinates". Is any chance that if I press that button more than once the variables not refresh and keeps their old values?  Happen that sometimes two different buttons use the same coordinates..so maybe I should reset the variables when I press the button... what do you think about?

Comment: yes you have to otherwise repeated values will come. You can use `array_unique()` to remove duplicates. but as i don't know about any variable in your code and what data they have i can not help much more. Thanks

Comment: The variables are numbers took it from the position Top and Left of different buttons. And this variables create an array with all "top-position" of different buttons and other one with "left-positions" . I'm gonna try the Array_unique...thanks for your help!! :)